# instagram API media popular by Hashtag

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Is it possible to have a filter for a specific hashtag in the instagram API for `media/popular`?
Will also work (if possible): `/tags/tag-name/media/recent` sorted by likes

Their documentation doesn't state it is possible, but I was wondering what is the easiest way to do it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instagram doesn't provides any filter for the media/recent, but they provide the number of likes of each picture. You can them save that on the database and sort it. Remember that you have to update database so the likes will be updated.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get the most popular tags using the API. The `media/popular` endpoint just gives you the trending images at that moment. The `/tags/tag-name/media/recent` only returns media for a single tag.

Comment: but I can't sort media/recent or anything... right?

Comment: @Boaz what would you sort in media/recent? I think it is returned in descending order of when the tag was assigned to the media.